# Java Balanced String not using stack

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to check if given String is balanced or not.
This is similar task like that one with balanced parenthesis.

[image: program]

Please let me know if this is understand for you.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: To be honest i dont know how to start.

Comment: why not using stack? also an array or list can be used like a stack.

Comment: i want do it without using stack

Comment: @maraca could you please tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class CheckBalance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(check("asdfgh()hgfdsa"));
    }

    static boolean isClosing(char first, char sec)
    {
        if (first == '(' && sec == ')') {
            return true;
        } else if (first == '{' && sec == '}' ) {
            return true;
        } else if (first == '[' && sec == ']') {
            return true;
        }//add other the different Chars
         else if(first == sec){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static boolean check(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            char[] valueAsArray = value.toCharArray();

            int size = valueAsArray.length;
            if (size == 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (size == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    if (!isClosing(valueAsArray[i], valueAsArray[size - (i+1)])){
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (i == (size-1)/2) {
                       break;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that i dont want use bracket. Just letters

Comment: just update the if condition to check !(valueAsArray[i] == valueAsArray[size - (i+1)]) and remove isClosing method.

Comment: it's not that simple because a letter can be opening or closing, brackets always do one of the two

Comment: Yep, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isBalanced(String s) {
    return isBalanced(s, 0, new LinkedList<>());
}

private boolean isBalanced(String s, int index, LinkedList<Character> stack) {
    if (index >= s.length())
        return stack.isEmpty();
    char c = s.charAt(index);
    if (!stack.isEmpty() && Character.compare(c, stack.getLast()) == 0) {
        stack.removeLast();
        if (isBalanced(s, index + 1, stack))
            return true;
        stack.add(c);
    }
    stack.add(c);
    return isBalanced(s, index + 1, stack);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this is possible to do it without stack?

Comment: this is a linked list not a stack, otherwise I would use the stack class

Answer (score 0):

ABAB is wrong right ? it is the same with parenthesis ?

```
public boolean isBalanceString(String input)
    {
        int firstIndex =0;
        int lastIndex = input.length()-1;
        while (firstIndex<lastIndex)
        {
            if(input.charAt(firstIndex) != input.charAt(lastIndex))
            {
                return false;
            }
            firstIndex++;
            lastIndex--;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yep its wrong, A is closing before B

Comment: so i think you just need to check the array[i] with array[array.lenght-1]. In case AABB is ok if it a valid parenthesis but it's not a balance String

Comment: Could you please show me the code?

Comment: check my comment

Comment: Sorry bro i dont understand

Comment: you can debug my code . It's very simple

Comment: Could you please write me code ?

Comment: Hi could you please help meb

Comment: check the code above mate

Comment: Yeah but it still not working in case like AABB

Comment: it's not working :*(

Comment: what about for example this "AABABBAB"